# Camel bean method run on another thread

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a question, that i hope it's simple..
I have a camel route, which make some action, there is a processor, this processor fill a threadLocal variable with a correlation id.
After this, it runs a .bean(mybean, "mymethod"), in this method i try to get my value from the threadLocal variable but it's null.

One thing i understand is camel run bean method on another thread ? is that true ?

I add another bean method call .bean(myBean, "myMethodForCorrelationId(correlationId)"), this method set the threadLocal variable and after .bean(mybean, "mymethod") can access to the right value of the threadLocal.

The code :

```
private void getRoute() {

    from(RouteConstant.INTERNAL)
    // id
    .routeId("myroute")
    .setHeader(ElkKeys.EVENT_TYPE.getElkKey(), constant(EventType.EXCHANGE_REQUEST_REPLAY))
    // extract header from query uri
    .process(filtersListProcessor).choice()
    // caching predicate
    .when(cachePrediate)
    // get from cache
    .to(RouteConstant.GET_FROM_CACHE_ROUTE).otherwise()

    .bean(mybean,"myMethodForCorrelationId(${header.correlationId})") // first call fill the threadLocal

    // second call, the method use the previous threadLocal variable and it works
    .bean(mybean,
            "myMethod( ${header."
                    + ElkKeys.QUERY_PARAMETERS.getElkKey() + "})") 

    .multicast()
    // put in cache
    .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, RouteConstant.PUT_INTO_CACHE_ROUTE).endChoice()

    .setHeader(ElkKeys.REPONSE_TIMESTAMP.getElkKey(), simple(RESPONSE_DATE_TIME))

    // send trace
    .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, RouteConstant.SEND_SUCCESS_TRACE_TO_ELK);
}
```

I search on google but i can't find anything about this, is the thread use for the 1st bean method will be the same for the second one (everytime in every situation) ?

If someone know the answer, i hope you can help me ..

Thx all,

Answer (score 1):

You describe a strange situation in your question. In fact **I don't see anything in your route that would enforce multithreading**.

Bean calls are **not** processed in other threads.

**By default, a Camel route is processed by 1 thread.** That means your `from` endpoint normally uses a thread pool to process multiple requests in parallel (for example HTTP or JMS endpoints), but each individual request is done by one thread. This thread routes the message through the complete route.

I quickly created this route and sent a message to it:

```
from("direct:input")
    .log("Camel Route: " + Thread.currentThread().getName())
    .process(new TestProcessor()) // writes Thread.currentThread().getName() to System.out
    .bean(new BeanThread()); // writes Thread.currentThread().getName() to System.out
```

The console output is as expected:

```
Camel Route: main
Processor: main
Bean: main
```

However, there are a couple of **"stateful" components** like an aggregator. As soon as you use one of these, the threading view on the route becomes more complicated.

But, as I wrote in the beginning, I don't see one of these in your route.

However, the big question is: **why do you want to use `ThreadLocal` variables?** The Camel way of saving values for later is putting them into the message header. Like this, you have the guarantee that a **value relevant for a given message is still present later** in the route.

Comment: Hey,
thx for your answer, infact i need to log a correlation ID when i log something.
And i try it with camel MDC but it doesnt work.
So i have try to put my correlation ID in a threadLocal variable in a processor and to get it in my bean but it is null 
So my conclusion was : my bean method run on another thread :/
But what you say is what i was thinking at the beginning.. I am going to look if i have something that force multithread

Comment: By the way: You can refactor your `Processor` into a Bean. The `Processor` interface is old and clumsy, Bean are much more elegant to test because you don't need to pass `Exchange`s around. Take a look at [this Camel Docs page about Parameter Binding Annotations](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/parameter-binding-annotations.html) to inject various message parts into POJO methods.

Comment: I was unsure about the Processor and did a quick route test. Both Processor and Bean are processed by the main thread. See my updated answer.